# What's the proper interpretation of: "I was kissed by a girl twice"?

Tags: semantics, ambiguity

The other day I experienced two distinct but similar events. I wanted to convey this to a friend and this is what came to mind:
"I was kissed by a girl twice."
My question is, does this sentence say, "I was kissed by the *same* girl twice," or "I was kissed by two different girls on two separate occasions?"

Similarly, what's the proper interpretation of this sentence:
"He got hit by a bicycle twice yesterday."  (Was he hit by the same bike twice?)

Answer (score 6):

I don't agree with @Alenanno's answer. The sentences you provided are ambiguous and it simply isn't clear at all whether it was the same girl/bike or not.

When I read the sentence *"I was kissed by a girl twice"*, I first though it were 2 separate girls on 2 separate occasions, then I read @Alenanno's answer and thought, "what the ... ?"

Also, in my mind, *"He got hit by a bicycle twice yesterday"* means he got hit by two different bicycles for the fact of his being an asshole. I don't see how 1 cyclist could cause 2 collisions with 1 person, sort of.

Short answer: The sentences are ambiguous, there's no definitive explanation of what they mean, only how people will perceive them.

Comment: If you say "*I was kissed by **a girl** twice.*" you think it's really ambiguous? "A girl" seems rather clear to me.

Comment: Yes, it definitely is ambiguous. It's called an **indefinite** article for a reason.

Comment: It really isn't. It's called **indefinite** because it doesn't specify the **WHO** not the number. It's a **singular** indefinite article.

Comment: Yes, it's expressed in **singular**, because there were never more than 1 girl kissing him at a time. No threesome for David, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't really agree, though. Seeing the votes, it seems I'm missing something. But I can't bring myself to think you can mean _two girls_ with that sentence.

Comment: @Alennano: "How many times have you eaten **a pizza**?" -"Uhm, about 200?" "So you have eaten 200 pizzas in total?" -"Yes."

Comment: I see what you mean. But that construction is different to me. Say you went to a party, the day after you get asked "What happened?" and you reply "I was kissed by a girl twice!" Will you think it's been two girls in different moments or the same girl?

Comment: @Alenanno, I will continue with your imaginary conversation: "I was kissed by a girl twice!" -"Oh, how did that happen?" "Well, we played spin the bottle and I was just lucky. First, the bottle pointed to Veronica, later to Kate."

Comment: @Alennano, the main point is that it is ambiguous; context determines it: "I was kissed by a girl twice!" - "Oh, how did that happen?" "Well, I won a bet with Carry and then she went for double or nothing. I won again."

Comment: @Alennano Let's try using brackets around parts of the sentence. "I was (kissed by a girl) twice" means that the event "kissed by a girl" has happened twice, without any indication as to how many girls. "I was kissed by (a girl) twice" means that the event "kissed by (a girl)" has happened twice - this is specifying the same (a girl) for each event. That's why it's ambiguous.

Comment: I would rather say "I was kissed by two girls," if I were kissed by two girls. "I was kissed by a girl twice" is ambiguous, as the adverb should be closer to the verb it modifies, if the phrase would mean "I was kissed twice."

Comment: I would imagine the likelihood of "a girl" representing a single referent across two events or a different referent for each event is a function of likely you think the event is of repeating per referent.  In the example I lean towards one girl because it seems a more ordinary context.  On the other hand "I was deported from a country twice" implies two different countries for me.  In both cases I can still accept the opposite choice though.

Answer (score 5):

How to deal with scope ambiguity is a big topic in computational linguistics. I could write a long answer, but it's been [dealt with before on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163099/scope-ambiguity-in-natural-language).

To answer the main question: there *is* no clear-cut, proper interpretation. Without context, it is declared ambiguous.

Comment: Refreshingly concise and correct.

Answer (score 3):

*I was kissed twice* doesn't say anything about how many girls; *I was kissed by two girls* says nothing about the number of kisses. *I was kissed by a girl twice* is ambiguous (probably one girl, possibly two). *He got hit by a bicycle twice yesterday* is similarly ambiguous, but more likely refers to two separate bicycles, simply because you're more likely to kiss the same girl twice than you are to be hit by the same bike twice.

*A girl* can refer to *any* girl, or *one* girl in particular, and you need to explicitly say which.

Perhaps this is as clear as you can get:

> Yesterday I was kissed once each by two [separate] girls.

Comment: If the sentence is "*I was kissed by a girl twice*", it *does* say how many girls; check my answer.

Comment: @Alenanno: I maintain that *a girl* is ambiguous between *one girl* and *any girl*, though with a bias toward *one*.

Comment: read my comment under Rimmer's answer.

Comment: "kissed once each by two" does not sound right to me - how about Yesterday two girls kissed me once each.

Comment: @mplungjan: It's the *once each* that's important. Where it goes is a matter of preference, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It is the passive that gets me.

*I was kissed twice by a girl*—perhaps I was in a room full of kissing people, boys and girls and one girl kissed me twice or two girls kissed me once.

If you turn it around

*Yesterday a girl kissed me twice*–then I have no doubt it was the same girl doing the kissing

Comment: If you have no doubt, then what is the difference between ""I was kissed by a girl twice." and "Yesterday a girl kissed me twice."? The position of the verb? I'm asking because my answer got downvoted for this so I want to see if that's the difference. Thanks. :)

Comment: Active versus passive. _Yesterday I was hit twice by something_ - ambiguous. _Yesterday something hit me twice_ - only one something (in my opinion)

Comment: @mplungjan, although you have a point, I think "Yesterday a policeman gave me a ticket twice." is still ambiguous (and consequently any active phrase, including the ones with girls; I do agree that with active you are more likely to interpret it as the same person, but I think that is largely due to the order of the word and the implied emphasis and that the context still plays a role). Though, I don't have hard references for my opinion.

Comment: I was ticketed by a policeman twice - could have been two policemen, in your example I would expect only one